# Change user id in linux

Tags: linux, uid

Here is a short description of what I want to do:

User tom has id 1000. I'm calling `usermod -u 2000 tom`.

What happens exactly besides that the id of tom changes to 2000? Do files and folders which were owned by this user still remain by this user or do I have to explicitly set the owner again?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`usermod` will change permissions for the user's files inside his home directory. files outside his home directory will have to be changed manually.

man usermod lists the following caveats:

> You must make certain that the named user is not executing any
>   processes when this command is being executed if the user's numerical
>   user ID, the user's name, or the user's home directory is being
>   changed.  usermod checks this on Linux, but only check if the user is
>   logged in according to utmp on other architectures.
>
> You must change the owner of any crontab files or at jobs manually.
>
> You must make any changes involving NIS on the NIS server.

Comment: is there any easy method to go through all files (not only home directory), check if they have the old uid and change it to the new one?

Comment: Is `find / -uid 1000 -exec chown -R tom {} \;` sufficient or do I have to do more?

Comment: You probably want to remove the `-R` in the `find`, as this makes the `chown` recursive.  It is common to have files owned by a different user then the directory containing those files.